# How set String value in listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, assets

I am using data store in Assets folder like "reader.txt" this data get in using "InputStream" geting string value like this set to String value in textview. My question is  how to store String in listview?

Here is my code:

```
try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("reader.txt");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();

        // Convert the buffer into a string.
        String text = new String(buffer);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        tv.setText(text);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Should never happen!
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: you should use ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read text from file, then store it into `String[]` and then use `ListAdapter` for example `ArrayAdapter<String>` with `ListView`.

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.someId);
your work with file ...
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, Layout, data)); 
// data is String[]
```

Here is similar example:

- [ArrayAdapter sample program in
  Android](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1516)

Difference with yours is that your `String[]` will be dynamically generated from file. So at first you will prepare data from file, store them into `String[]` and set them into Adapter.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways by which you can store strings in listView. Either you can use `android:entries` which takes an array or object resource as an input, or u can use ArrayAdapter to set entries in listView.I will show you an example.

```
 String[] values={""}//whatever values you have shown in the TextView
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


     // Assign adapter to ListView
     listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```